# Wait for two observables to finish

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have two List - each list has it's API and for each item I have to call API (with retrofit2 - android).

Can I do something like this?

How can I subscribe to their both finish?

```
    Observable<Integer> offerObservable = Observable.from(restDatabaseImages.getOfferImages());
    Observable<Integer> otherOfferObservable = Observable.from(restDatabaseImages.getOtherOfferImages());

    offerObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<RestOfferImage>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RestOfferImage> call(Integer integer) {
            return backendService.getDatabaseOfferImage(integer);
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<RestOfferImage>() {
        @Override
        public void call(RestOfferImage restOfferImage) {
            offerService.saveOfferImage(restOfferImage);
        }
    });

    otherOfferObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<RestOtherOfferImage>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RestOtherOfferImage> call(Integer integer) {
            return backendService.getDatabaseOtherOfferImage(integer);
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<RestOtherOfferImage>() {
        @Override
        public void call(RestOtherOfferImage restOtherOfferImage) {
            otherOfferService.saveOtherOfferImage(restOtherOfferImage);
        }
    });
```

-- 
**UPDATE:**

I tried to rewrite it as this. The problem is that I see only first flatMap Func1 executed - for first entry ...

```
Observable<Integer> offerObservable = Observable.from(restDatabaseImages.getOfferImages());
Observable<Integer> otherOfferObservable = Observable.from(restDatabaseImages.getOtherOfferImages());

Observable ob1 = offerObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<RestOfferImage>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<RestOfferImage> call(Integer integer) {
        return backendService.getDatabaseOfferImage(integer);
    }
}).map(new Func1<RestOfferImage, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call(RestOfferImage restOfferImage) {
        offerService.saveOfferImage(restOfferImage);
        return null;
    }
});

Observable ob2 = otherOfferObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<RestOtherOfferImage>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<RestOtherOfferImage> call(Integer integer) {
        return backendService.getDatabaseOtherOfferImage(integer);
    }
}).map(new Func1<RestOtherOfferImage, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call(RestOtherOfferImage restOtherOfferImage) {
        otherOfferService.saveOtherOfferImage(restOtherOfferImage);
        return null;
    }
});

ob1.zipWith(ob2, new Func2() {
    @Override
    public Object call(Object o, Object o2) {
        return null;
    }
}).subscribe(new Subscriber() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.d("AllDone", "DA");
        onLoadingFinishedListenerCallback.onLoading2Finished();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object o) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Your second version looks ok more or less. If you don't see 2nd flat map called, it likely means that an observable returned from restDatabaseImages.getOtherOfferImages() never emits an item. 
Also could you paste the output.

Comment: @yurgis, sorry, I meant 2nd flatMap isn't called, but also 1nd map isn't called. I've placed Log.d() so I'm sure.

Comment: Please Correct your question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void testSample() {
        Integer[] offerImages = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Integer[] otherOfferImages = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        Observable<Integer> offerObservable = Observable.from(offerImages).flatMap(someInt -> fakeApiCall(someInt));
        Observable<Integer> otherOfferObservable = Observable.from(otherOfferImages).flatMap(someInt -> fakeApiCall(someInt));

        Observable.zip(
                offerObservable,
                otherOfferObservable,
                (offer, otherOffer) -> String.format("Offer: %d - Other Offer: %d", offer, otherOffer)
        ).subscribe(data -> System.out.println(data));
    }

    private Observable<? extends Integer> fakeApiCall(Integer someInt) {
        return Observable.just(someInt * 10);
    }
}
```

`Zip` operator will ensure that you will emit those events together, and then you can generate a new stream with them.

The code above will print this:

```
Offer: 10 - Other Offer: 60
Offer: 20 - Other Offer: 70
Offer: 30 - Other Offer: 80
Offer: 40 - Other Offer: 90
Offer: 50 - Other Offer: 100
```

Comment: Thanks! What if offerImages or otherOfferImages is empty? I would like like to execute "subscribe(data -> System.out.println(data)".